# How can I avoid inline styling, yet take advantage of the templating language?

Tags: django, django-templates

For each instantiation of an object in the template, I'd like to extract it's associated ImageField's url in order to show the photo. But I'm having trouble finding a way to do this without inline styling:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col s4">
            <div class="card-panel" style="background-image: url('{{entry.image.url}}');">

        <h1>{{entry.title}}</h1>

        </div></div></div>
    {% endfor %}
```

This works in bringing each individual image to the template, but I wonder if I can abstract away the css just to keep my css in a separate file.

edit:  same goes for the `<img>` tag:

`<img src="{{ entry.image.url }}">`

this, in the template, would be dynamic. But I wouldn't be able to set this as a `background-image`

Comment: Use `<img` tag and style the image in your seperate css file

Comment: @RajaSimon same situation for the <img> tag. i'll edit in an example into the post

Comment: There's no way you can have a dynamic style with a static css.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers so how do django devs handle a situation like this? If i wanted each template object to display its image as a background image, how should i go about it?

Comment: Just like you did: using an inline style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use the Django template system to render CSS and create dynamic css files. I don't recommend doing this, but if you really want to you can set it up like normal url/view.

For example, your urls.py would have something like this

`url(r'^dynamic_style/(?P<pk>\w+)$', dynamic_style, name='dynamic')`

Then your view would look something like

```
def dynamic_style(request, pk):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk)   

    return render_to_response('dynamic_style.css', {
        'image_url': entry.image.url
    }, content_type='text/css')
```

Then in your template you could have

```
<link href="{% url 'dynamic_style' pk=entry.id %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is a clunky way to generate css. If you can use inline as suggested above, it's much better.